# Adding value to map syntax

Tags: scala, dictionary, traits

Having a map

```
val m = Map("foo" -> 1, ("bar" -> 2), ("foobar", 3))
```

I can add new element by

```
m + ("boo" -> 3)
```

or

```
val a = ("fff", 2); m + a
```

but when I do

```
m + ("ggg", 2)
```

I get

```
error   : type mismatch;
found   : String("ggg")
required: (String, ?)
          m + ("ggg", 2)
               ^
```

Could you please clarify why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m + ("ggg", 2)` is equivalent to `m.+("ggg", 2)` which is passing `"ggg"` and `2` respectively to the method `+`. If you want to pass them as a tuple, then write `m + (("ggg", 2))`, or `m + ("ggg" -> 2)` as you already know.